# Span to input text to span

Tags: javascript, jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What's the best edit-in-place plugin for jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/708801/whats-the-best-edit-in-place-plugin-for-jquery)

For example, when you click on a span, it becomes an input-text, and when you click outside the span it becomes an span again, and you could edit the input text. So you basicly change the tag name when you click on it.

But how can you do that? Showing and hiding spans and input-text's  does not look like the best solution..

Comment: once span become input, then how you can click out side span? :)

Comment: @JohnP Oh! I didn't knew that topic, that it was called an edit-in-place! Thanks! It helped me :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here, take a look at that, it's simplified, but should help you : http://jsfiddle.net/RUwtt/

Html :

```
<span>My value here!</span>
```

Javascript :

```
$(function () {
    $('span').live('click', function () {
        var input = $('<input />', {'type': 'text', 'name': 'aname', 'value': $(this).html()});
        $(this).parent().append(input);
        $(this).remove();
        input.focus();
    });

    $('input').live('blur', function () {
        $(this).parent().append($('<span />').html($(this).val()));
        $(this).remove();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Some Browsers support the 'contenteditable'-attribute, which makes it possible to just click the element and edit the content. You could catch the focus and blur events of you editable elements to save the changes.

See: 
http://html5demos.com/contenteditable

Answer (score 1):

We have such a solution in production. A form displays information about a contact with span tags, along with an edit image. When clicked, the span tag rotate to show an input text to do modifications... We are using the [JQuery Flip](http://lab.smashup.it/flip/) plugin to handle this. The final effetc is pretty slicky