# FormCollection - how to get non-input fields?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

User inserts new records in the table in his browser with no postback (using jQuery). After all is done user presses "save" and i need to postback all new table rows data to the server. I know that it's possible using $.post with parameters. How to do it using generic postback (form.submit)? Seemes FormCollection as controller action parameter contains only keys that relate to input fields, not read-only like `<tr>` or `<span>`.
Could you advise how to get table rows data using generoc postback? Thank you.

Comment: Mystere Man, thank you! I've checked all answers that helped me.

Comment: Darin, ok, since now i know that :)

Comment: @jim, now that you have learned how to accept answers, I would recommend you to learn how to ask questions. Here are some good resources that I invite you to read: http://sscce.org and http://tinyurl.com/so-hints

Comment: What i've done wrong? I typed it and saw similar questions and didnt find the answer. Was anything not clean in there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The name "FormsCollection" implies a collection of Forms elements.  `<tr>` tags and `<span>` elements are not forms elements, therefore it is not logical to think they would be posted to a FormsCollection.

Any data you want back must be in input elements.  There is no other way, other than using an ajax post.

Comment: >it is not logical to think they would be posted to a FormsCollection

Disagree. What if the user want to switch out span with input as the user clicks on them, such as in [this example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6199594/span-to-input-text-to-span)? I think this is still a legitimate use case.

Comment: @16807 - You're being ridiculous.  If you convert them to inputs, then they're no long spans or tr's.  So it doesn't apply.  It's like saying "Well sure, nothing can go faster than the speed of light, but what if you made light go faster?"  Yeah, ok.. but it still doesn't change the parameters of what was asked.

Comment: I do not believe you understand my statement. In such a setup information is stored in spans. If the user wishes to edit something it is only converted to input for however long the element has focus. If the content moves back to a span, it presumably can no longer be transferred to the server, at least in this context.

Comment: @16807 - It's still not logical to think that spans or tr's would be posted to a FormsCollection.

Comment: Not logical by the framework's definition of the parameter, i.e. a "collection of forms", however I'm pointing out the definition may not be sufficiently generic and there is some logic in expecting a framework to allow for this behavior.

Comment: @16807 - This is not a framework issue at all.  Simply put, a browser does not submit anything but form data that lives within a form element.  If it's not a form field, it won't be submitted by the browser, and there's nothing the framework can do about it, short of doing a custom ajax submit which the asker specifically did not want to do.  This is a limitation of the HTML specification, and something all web frameworks must live with.

Answer (score 1):

It's difficult without using a client side library like Knockout.JS.

http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2010/07/12/editing-a-variable-length-list-knockout-style/
http://knockoutjs.com/

Comment: @jim - No, steven sanderson is a well known expert in MVC, and has written one of the most famous books on the subject.  You should not make judgements like that.

Comment: I'll happily give KO free advertising. It's saved me so much time.